# Same name field with different type in two different subsite list not included in search crawld

Tags: search-scope

I have same name field 'Amount' with types 'Number' and 'Currency' in different sub site list.
I run full crawl but when i search for amount with currency in first sub site , it display result. whereas in second with number field it not work.

So i changed field number type to currency type then rerun the full crawled but still not work. Then after i delete manage property for that field ,reset search index ,restart search service and recreate mange property for that field and rerun full crawled but not work.

Is there any solution for this issue?